# Field tactic with partial inverse function

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Coq defines the multiplicative inverse function `1/x` as a total function `R -> R`, both in Rdefinitions.v and in Field_theory.v. The value `1/0` is left undefined, all calculation axioms ignore it.

However this is a problem in constructive mathematics, because all total functions `R -> R` must be continuous. And we cannot connect the positive and negative infinities at zero. Therefore the constructive inverse is rather a partial function :

```
Finv : forall x : R, (0 < x \/ x < 0) -> R
```

This is for example how it is defined in the [C-CoRN](https://github.com/coq-community/corn) library.

Now is there a way to use the `field` tactic with those partial inverse functions ? A direct `Add Field` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.  The `Add Field` command relies on a function of type `R -> R` that represents the inverse and such a function cannot be defined constructively.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know another tactic to simplify field expressions with a partial inverse function?